# SQL Server Bulk insert error - file not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, networking, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to import the CSV file values using bulk insert but I'm getting an error in my code.

Can anyone help me with this?

The following is the code I wrote:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

BULK INSERT JBLOADER.dbo.FBNK_TELLER 
FROM "\\Karthick\c\sql\FBNK_TELLER_4_0.csv"
WITH
(
     CODEPAGE = 1251,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = '?',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)
GO

SELECT CONVERT(varchar,@@ROWCOUNT) + ' rows affected'
GO
```

And I am getting an error:

> Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot bulk load. The file "\Karthick\c\sql\FBNK_TELLER_4_0.csv" does not exist.

But I can access the path `\\Karthick\c\sql\` from run mode & the file is there. Kindly note that server is installed on the same machine.

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: try to map that folder and see how it goes.

Comment: I have already mapped the folder & the same problem persist again..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BULK insert error with UNC path and windows Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852117/bulk-insert-error-with-unc-path-and-windows-authentication)

Comment: Let's close it. It is a user stackexchange error (not bothering to search) and a double of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852117/bulk-insert-error-with-unc-path-and-windows-authentication